# How to import full directories without specifying the `index.js` file in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a project structure like:

```
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── registerController.js
│   └── routes
│       ├── index.js
│       └── registerRoutes.js
├── app.js
├── config
│   ├── firebase
│   │   └── firebase.json
│   └── index.js
├── data
│   ├── htmlHeaderData.js
│   └── index.js
├── database
│   └── index.js
├── public
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── main.css
│   │   ├── register.css
│   │   └── reset.css
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── icon
│   │   └── website-images
│   │       └── register-images
│   │           └── authentication-bg.jpg
│   └── js
│       ├── main.js
│       └── register.js
├── utils
└── views
    ├── index.ejs
    ├── mainBottom.ejs
    ├── mainTop.ejs
    └── register.ejs
```

In my app.js, I am trying to import the routes like:

```
import router from "./app/routes";
```

The `index.js` of the routes looks like:

```
// Imports
import express        from "express";
import registerRouter from "./registerRoutes.js";
// Global Variables
const router = express.Router();
// Route definitions
router.use("/register",registerRouter);
// Exports
export default router;
```

For some reason, it isn't able to resolve and import it. However, when I specify the import as `import router from "./app/routes/index.js";`, it is. I've read that I should, notwithstanding, be able to import it without specifying it.

I've not been able to understand the problem. How can I import the routes without specifying the `index.js` file directly, but instead only the dir?

Comment: *it isn't able to resolve and import it*. Is there any error?